# ¿Por qué éste menú no me presnta la lista de opciones para elegir?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Disponemos de un DataFrame 'df_final' con varias columnas.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import date

start_day = "2000-1-4"
end_day = date.today()
    
dicc_tickers = {"IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "TEF.MC":"Telefonica", "R4.MC":"Renta4", "^IBEX":"Ibex35", "^GSPC":"S&P500", 
                "^IXIC":"Nasdaq", "^N225":"Nikkey_225", "^DJI":"DowJons", "^STOXX50E":"Eurostoxx50",  
                "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", 
                'AAPL':"Apple", 'MSFT':"Microsoft", 'GOOG':"Google", 'SAN':'Santander', 'REP.MC': 'Repsol', 
               'GOOG': 'Google', 'BBVA': 'B_Bilbao', 'SPY': 'SPY', '^GSPC': 'SP500', '^VIX':'VIX'}
dfs = []
nombres = []
 
for (k,v) in dicc_tickers.items():
    #cotizaciones_de_ticker = pdr.DataReader(k, 'yahoo', start, end)
    cotizaciones_de_ticker = yf.download(k, start= start_day, end = end_day, progress=False)
    cotizaciones_de_ticker = cotizaciones_de_ticker[["Close"]]
    cotizaciones_de_ticker = cotizaciones_de_ticker.rename(columns={"Close": v})                                                              
    dfs.append(cotizaciones_de_ticker)
df_final = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

La siguiente función pretende , uilizando el método 'enumerate', presentar una relación, con un índice correlativo apartir del 1, de las etiquetas de todas las columnas, permitiéndonos elegir un número de ellas para conformar otro DataFrame.

```
# Seleccionar valores y crear un DataFrame con el portfolio.
def select_stocks( df_final):
    available_stocks = df_total.columns.tolist()
    for i, name in enumerate(available_stocks):
        print(f"{i+1}: {name}")
    selected_stocks = []
    while True:
        try:
            n_stocks = input("Ingrese el número de acciones para incluir en el portfolio, o 'q' para salir: ")
            if n_stocks == 'q':
                break
            n_stocks = int(n_stocks)
            if n_stocks <= 0:
                raise ValueError("El número de acciones debe ser mayor que cero.")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Ingrese un número válido o 'q' para salir.")
    if n_stocks != 'q':
        for i in range(n_stocks):
            while True:
                try:
                    stock_index = input(f"Ingrese el índice de la acción #{i+1} para incluir en el portfolio, o 'q' para salir: ")
                    if stock_index == 'q':
                        break
                    stock_index = int(stock_index)
                    if stock_index < 1 or stock_index > len(available_stocks):
                        raise ValueError(f"El índice de la acción debe estar entre 1 y {len(available_stocks)}.")
                    if available_stocks[stock_index-1] in selected_stocks:
                        raise ValueError("La acción ya ha sido seleccionada.")
                    break
                except ValueError as e:
                    print(e)
            if stock_index == 'q':
                break
            selected_stocks.append(available_stocks[stock_index-1])
        portfolio_df = df_total.loc[:, selected_stocks]
    else:
        portfolio_df = None
    return portfolio_df
    
portfolio_df = select_stocks(df_final) 
portfolio_df
```

Sin embargo, no mepresenta la lista de opciones, pasando directamente a

"Ingrese el número de acciones para incluir en el portfolio, o 'q' para salir:  3"

"Ingrese el índice de la acción #1 para incluir en el portfolio, o 'q' para salir:"

¿Cuál puede ser el error?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: No te habrás confundido de variable y en vez de ser `df_total` sería `df_final`?

Comment: Efectivamente. Corrijo el error